# Add a Constructor to a C# System Class

Tags: c#, constructor

I want to add an additional copy constructor to the `System.Drawing.RectangleF` class that would take another `RectangleF` as its sole parameter.

I tried making a partial class in the System.Drawing namespace and it gave me a namespace collision. I tried just making it using an extension class, and it won't treat it as a constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case of `RectangleF`, you don't have to actually do anything, because `RectangleF` is a **struct**, and so it has **value semantics**. Assigning the Rect to a variable copies its contents.

Take the following example code:

```
RectangleF a = new RectangleF(1, 2, 3, 4);
Console.WriteLine(a);
RectangleF b = a;   //a gets copied to b
Console.WriteLine(b);
a.X = 5;
a.Y = 6;
a.Width = 7;
a.Height = 8;
Console.WriteLine(a);
Console.WriteLine(b);
```

And when you run it, you'll get the following output:

```
{X=1,Y=2,Width=3,Height=4}
{X=1,Y=2,Width=3,Height=4}
{X=5,Y=6,Width=7,Height=8}
{X=1,Y=2,Width=3,Height=4}
```

You can see the value of a is copied to b, and then b stays unchanged when you modify a. If `RectangleF` was an actual class, it would have reference semantics and the last two lines of output would be the same thing.

Comment: I marked this as the answer because it does resolve my specific question. However, it would be nice to know if there was a general solution for when I do try to extend a built-in class and want to add a new constructor.

Comment: @JKreft: the answer to that is simple: not possible.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can only use the partial class feature if you effectively own the class.  That is you can't partial a class in another DLL as is the case here.

The RectangleF is a struct, btw, not a class, not that this really changes anything.

You might look into [extension methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx); you wouldn't be able to define a constructor, but you could define an extension method that let's you do:

```
var newRectangleF = existingRectangleF.clone ();
```

Extension methods can be defined across DLL boundaries, and can invoked using instance method syntax or a static method syntax.  They work nicely with Visual Studio, such as in completion suggestions.

---

You also might find `MemberwiseClone()` interesting.

Comment: An extension method will only work if you don't need access to the class's innards, unless you plan on invoking some Reflection magic.

Comment: I don't need access to the innards really, I intended to just take the incoming `RectangleF` and pass its `.Location` and `.Size` to the built-in constructor.